# Make a directory under newly created directory

Tags: php

As stated in the title,
how would I make a directory under a newly created directory in PHP?

```
 if (!file_exists(XXX)) {
mkdir(XXX);
//THEN HERE, I WANT TO MAKE A FILE UNDER "XXX"
}
```

I've tried adding another `mkdir();`,
such as `mkdir(XXX."/YYY")`,

but am not getting results.

Comment: Are you trying to make a directory over a directory, or making the directory on the root of the created directory?

Comment: @JoelHernandez the latter. Thanks.

Comment: I believe I already answered below. You can think of it as a "pointer" , to check your current directory echo getcwd(); , every time you execute mkdir(); or fopen(); or any file system related method you'll be executing it inside that directory, by this whenever you create a directory, It will always be on the root directory, unless you change the "pointer" by using chdir("directory"); Whenever you do this, all the file system related methods will be executed on the new changed directory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your question . Here are three possible scenarios.

If you want to **create a directory within a recently created directory**: (0000 stands for permissions)

```
 if(!file_exists("new")){
            mkdir("new",0777); //Making base directory new
            mkdir("new/new2",0000,true); //Adding directory new2 to new

    }
```

If you wish to **make a directory on the same directory that your other directory resides** , follow the same process.

```
mkdir("added",0777); //This directory will be created in the directory where "new" is.
```

If you want to **go back one directory and then create a new directory in there** you can change your directory to `..` as `chdir("..");` and then create a directory in there.

And finally if you wish to **create a file on the directory recently created** , you could move to that directory and then create it there, here's some example code:

```
if(!file_exists("new")){
        mkdir("new",0777); //Making the directory "new"
}
chdir("new"); //Changing the working directory to "new"
if($handle=fopen("newFile.txt","w")){ //Creating the new file in "new".
    fwrite($handle,"Writing to new file."); //Writing to the file.
}
fclose($handle); //Closing the file
```